# Using a custom adapter to set an image source in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I use a custom leaderboard adapter to bind the data to a recyclerview. The data is parsed like so (the data is fetched from a database, binded post execute):

```
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); ++i)
                {
                    JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                    String fname = obj.getString("fname");
                    String lname = obj.getString("lname");
                    int elo = Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("elo"));
                    int hotstreak = Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("hotstreak"));
                    // Add to player array
                    TennisUser player = new TennisUser(fname, lname, elo, hotstreak);
                    players.add(player);
                }
                Collections.sort(players, (p1, p2) -> p2.getElo() - p1.getElo());
                recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.ladder_recyclerview);
                LadderAdapter ladderAdapter = new LadderAdapter(getApplicationContext(), players);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(ladderAdapter);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
                recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getApplicationContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
```

If the player is on a hotstreak, indicated by 1, I set the image source to the hotstreak icon in the following code:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull LadderViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.rank.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));
        holder.fname.setText(p.get(position).getFname());
        holder.lname.setText(p.get(position).getLname());
        if (p.get(position).getHotstreak() == 1)
        {
            holder.hotstreak.setImageResource(R.drawable.hot_streak);
        }
    }
```

For testing purposes, only the first user in the list has a hotstreak, I have checked the array values after parsing and the data is correct (only the first user with hotstreak = 1). However for some reason, if anyone in the list has a hotstreak, the app also displays the last in the list with a hotstreak as well. I have debugged the process and it only enters the if statement when the condition is met. The imageview xml is:

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_hotstreak"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="22dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/lname_text"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/fname_text"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />
```

I can provide any more detail necessary, I'm just not sure if I'm missing something glaringly obvious. Thanks!

Comment: Post post your code in the question as code and not an image.

Comment: A RecyclerView will recycle views in each row. Have you tried unsetting the image resource in `onBindViewHolder` for those cases where the user is not on a hotstreak?

Comment: @codebod I guess that was something I should have tried! It works, thanks. I'm still not sure why it would only incorrectly show the image for the very last item in the recyclerview though?

Answer (score -1):

CustomAdapter MyClassAdapter.class

```
private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView Id;
    ImageView Image;
    TextView Name;
    TextView Description;
    TextView Type;
    TextView Cost;
    TextView Count;
    TextView Comment;
    Button Buttonup;
    Button Buttondown;
}

public MyClassAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Plate> items) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final Plate item = getItem(position);
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(this.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_main, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.Id = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.code);
        viewHolder.Image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        viewHolder.Name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        viewHolder.Description = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        viewHolder.Cost = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
        viewHolder.Count = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.count);
        viewHolder.Buttonup = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_up);
        viewHolder.Buttondown = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_down);



        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    if (item!= null) {
        viewHolder.Id.setText(String.format("%d",item.getId()));
        viewHolder.Image.setImageURI(item.getImage());
        viewHolder.Name.setText(String.format("%s", item.getName()));
        viewHolder.Description.setText(String.format("%s", item.getDescription()));
        viewHolder.Name.setText(String.format("%s", item.getName()));
        viewHolder.Cost.setText(String.format("%s", item.getCost()));
        viewHolder.Count.setText(String.format("%d", item.getCount()));
        viewHolder.Buttonup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DBHelper mydb= new DBHelper(getContext());
                mydb.AddPlate(item.getId());
                item.CountUp();
               //update viewholder.Count
            }
        });
        viewHolder.Buttondown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DBHelper mydb= new DBHelper(getContext());
                mydb.RemovePlate(item.getId());
                item.CountDown();
                //update viewholder.Count
            }
        });
    }
    return convertView;
}




// And calls the custom ArrayAdapter from Activity
      ArrayList<Plate> FullMenu;
        FullMenu = mydb.getPlates("Entrees");
        Plate p;
        int i;
        MyClassAdapter adapter = new MyClassAdapter(this,0,FullMenu);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        for (i=0; i < FullMenu.size(); i++) {
            p = FullMenu.get(i);
            adapter.add(p);
        }
```